# How do I check how many Gold Sheldon Licenses I have?

Tags: splatoon-3

In Sheldon's weapon shop I can spend Gold Sheldon Licenses I got from importing my Splatoon 2 save to unlock weapons before reaching the level requirement. There's a counter that shows how many normal Sheldon Licenses I have, but how do I check how many Gold Sheldon Licenses I have?

[image: spending a Gold Sheldon License]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [splatoon wiki](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Sheldon_License):

> Gold Sheldon Licenses do not have a counter in the user interface.
> Instead, Sheldon will tell the player how many they have left after
> they make a purchase.

[image: Sheldon saying how many Gold Sheldon Licenses are left]

So I guess they expected you to just spend them real quick and move on, and didn't bother programming it in the interface.

Answer (score -1):

If you **use all of your silver licenses**, the display will instead show the number of gold licenses you have.  Since this is a resource limited to importing data from Splatoon 2 as far as I can tell (doing so only gives you 3 gold licenses and there is no other way to acquire them), it seems they did not assign much thought into having a good UX for displaying them.

Comment: Gold Sheldon Licenses isn't provided by preordering. Player will receive it only when they have Splatoon 2's save data, as OP wrote it in above.

Comment: @Skye-AT You're right, I misremembered.  Thanks for the correction

Comment: May be worth mentioning importing your Splatoon 2 save grants 3 gold licenses

Comment: I used all my silver licenses, but the game did not display how many gold licenses I had.

Comment: If that is the case now, it has been changed or broken with the recent update.  I absolutely remember it working this way upon release.  It may have required a reload of the shop.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann If you use all your silver licenses but still have gold licenses, the cost indicator on weapons you're high enough level to purchase changes from 1 silver license to 1 gold license. Could that be what you're thinking of?

Comment: @Stevoisiak That could be the case.  Either way, Nintendo really put no thought into having two separate currencies available for this shop

Comment: @ChaseSandmann They likely figured it wasn't needed since you can only ever get 3 gold licenses.